# Click on a disabled Jquery UI Slider goes to top of page

Tags: jquery-ui

When you click on a JQuery UI slider that is disabled and the page has been scrolled down, the page goes back to the top.

This is happening because the slider widget is implemented with an anchor tag containing an Href of #.

This is my hack solution.

```
$(".ui-slider-disabled").on("click",
                            ".ui-slider-handle",
                            function () {return false;});
```

It works well but, is there a native (API) way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this (you may need to change the class, depending on how you set it up)

```
$(".ui-slider").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: It's not really a propagation problem.  Since it is an anchor tag with # as the href and the other events have been disabled, it's defaulting to the standard click event.

Comment: Yes, that definitely works but I was hoping to find an API solution.

Comment: Does it need to be with an anchor tag?

Comment: It's part of the widget.